# Dendrogram fails to plot in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am doing Hierarchical Clustering in R following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7UHwPcpF8Y).

My code is like this but it ends in an error:

```
> distances = dist(movies[2:20], method="euclidean")
> clusterMovies = hclust(distances, method="ward")
> plot(clusterMovies)
Error in plot.hclust(clusterMovies) : 'merge' matrix has invalid contents
```

Answer (score 0):

It works OK for me... Be sure that you download the `movieLens.txt` file with the exact way shown in the [previous video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOKmD6MOIgg) of the tutorial, i.e **do not use 'Save as' and Internet Explorer**. Then this should work:

```
movies = read.table("movieLens.txt", header=FALSE, sep="|",quote="\"")

# Add column names
colnames(movies) = c("ID", "Title", "ReleaseDate", "VideoReleaseDate", "IMDB", "Unknown", "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Childrens", "Comedy", "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", "Fantasy", "FilmNoir", "Horror", "Musical", "Mystery", "Romance", "SciFi", "Thriller", "War", "Western")

# Remove unnecessary variables
movies$ID = NULL
movies$ReleaseDate = NULL
movies$VideoReleaseDate = NULL
movies$IMDB = NULL

# Remove duplicates
movies = unique(movies)

# Compute distances
distances = dist(movies[2:20], method = "euclidean")

# Hierarchical clustering
clusterMovies = hclust(distances, method = "ward") 

# Plot the dendrogram
plot(clusterMovies)
```

apart from a harmless warning message, after the `clustermovies` command:

```
The "ward" method has been renamed to "ward.D"; note new "ward.D2"
```